# java.security.SignatureException: error decoding signature bytes

Tags: android, exception, android-4.4-kitkat, ecdsa

I am getting this exception when trying to verify the signature in an Android KitKat device (Nexus 5).

Using `KeyFactory` as the EC algorithm and signature instance as `NONEwithECDSA`.

Exception Log:

```
java.security.SignatureException: error decoding signature bytes. 
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.DSABase.engineVerify(DSABase.java:82)
at java.security.Signature$SignatureImpl.engineVerify(Signature.java:617)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:375)
```

Can anyone explain how to overcome this error?